# Parameter value sent to but not received by action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I initiate loading scans through this action:

```
export function loadPickingScans (orderReference) {
    return { type: SCANNING_LOAD_SCANS, orderReference };
}
```

It's called in my smart (page) component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { loadPickingScans } = this.props;
    loadPickingScans(this.props.match.params.orderReference);
}
```

This is the url:

`enter code here`http://localhost:3000/orders/my-order-reference/scans

`this.props.match.params.orderReference` correctly contains `my-order-reference`.

However, adding a log to my action, orderReference is received as `undefined`.

> What should I do to receive this expected value?

**Update**

By request:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadPickingScans: () => dispatch(loadPickingScans())
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the page component?

Comment: can you show you mapDispatchToProps

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mapDispatchToProps`, while dispatching the action, you haven't passed any argument to it and hence it logs undefined in the method, you need to write it like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadPickingScans: (value) => dispatch(loadPickingScans(value))
    };
}
```

or simply

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
   loadPickingScans
}
```

Comment: Yup, my penny dropped as you requested this info, but good catch!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)